# Restore suspended state of VM after it failed to resume in VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware Workstation Pro on Windows. I tried resuming a suspended VM, but it failed with some error. Workstation usually asks if I want to preserve the suspended state, but not this time, so the WM is now shown as turned off.

The memory (`.vmem`) and suspend state (`.vmss`) files are still present in the VM's folder. Is there a way to make Workstation recognize the VM as suspended so I can try resuming it again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close VMware Workstation.
2. In the virtual machine configuration (`.vmx`) file, set `checkpoint.vmState` to the `.vmss` file, e.g.:

   ```
   checkpoint.vmState = "Ubuntu-f9999b3e.vmss"
   ```
3. Delete any stuck `.lck` folders.
4. If we try resuming now, it fails. Let's look at `vmware.log`:

   ```
   DUMPER: Bad magic 0xbad1bad1 in header, 'F:\VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-f9999b3e.vmss'.
   ```

   If we look at a working `.vmss` file with a hex editor, we can see that the correct header is `0xD2`, `0xBE`, `0xD2`, `0xBE` (`0xbed2bed2`). So we set the first 4 bytes of our `.vmss` to that.